# Key/Value saving to a lot of keys effectively

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, key-value

I am using key/value method to save integer to NSUserDefaults. I have like 30 different cases in a switch and case where each case saves an integer value to a specific key. And I have created one method for each integer that is being saved. Heres some code to explain:

```
-(void) saveInteger1:(NSInteger)int1 {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:int1 forKey:@"Integer1"];
}
-(void) saveInteger2:(NSInteger)int2 {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:int2 forKey:@"Integer2"];
}
-(void) saveInteger3:(NSInteger)int3 {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:int3 forKey:@"Integer3"];
}
//And I got from 1-30 of these methods

switch (newInteger) {
    case 1:
    [self saveInteger1:newInteger];
    break;
    case 2:
    [self saveInteger2:newInteger];
    break;
    case 3:
    [self saveInteger3:newInteger];
    break;
//And from 1-30 cases
}
```

What is a more effectively way to do this so it won't be so many lines of code?

Comment: So I guess that your code snippet is just an example, because if you literally do like you've written, it would be entirely useless to have defaults with @"Integer1":1, @"Integer2":2, etc...

Comment: Yeah, this isn't exactly the code I was using..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are all of the keys of the form `IntegerX`? If so then do:

```
- (void)saveInteger:(NSInteger)value {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Integer%d", value];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:value forKey:key];
}

[self saveInteger:newInteger];
```

No `switch` statement is required.

Comment: Ok for the answer, but this is not needed. Why using N keys if every key may hold just one possible value?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Read the question. He wants different keys.

Comment: I know he wants different keys, I'm saying he doesn't need them. His key-value pairs are @"Integer1": 1, @"Integer2":2, @"Integer3":3 ; Why ?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri The goal of the original code is unclear. But without further info from the OP, it's difficult to be sure what is really appropriate.